# How does Allah warn us about bad company (friend and family)

Tags: sin

Is there anywhere in the Quran that states warning of bad company, how’re we supposed to know if people are bad for us or not meant for us please use Quranic verses if there are any, if not please just inform me bad effects on us of bad company or how we should spot that Allah doesn’t want this person in our life

Answer (score 1):

There are several verses in the Glorious Qur'an that guides us about who we should keep company with and not. We can collaborate with all human beings over worldly affairs but if any interaction with someone leads to disobeying Allah and His messenger, then their alliance or friendship or that disobeying act involving them is not worth it. 
Our friends have great influence over us. We do many things just out of peer pressure too. So we need to be cautious about who we take us friends because we will become like them over time or take things from them that seem good to us though it may be bad. It happens in a very subtle manner even before we realize. 
 Sometimes it is preferred that a good person is among the bad ones only so that he or she guides the others and become a positive influence to them instead. (Provided the good person is mature and strong enough to resist the bad things from the others taking over him). Do your best. If things are not working just maintain a distance from their bad aspects but do keep trying especially if its a family member that needs guidance. 
If you are not sure if someone's company is bad or not, you can resort to the Istikharah prayer for guidance in any matter.

> `The description of Salat al-Istikharah was narrated by Jabir ibn ‘Abd-Allah al-Salami, who said:` 
>
>
> "The Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) used to teach his companions to make Istikharah in all things, just as he used to teach them Surahs from the Qur'an. He (SAW) said: 'If any one of you is concerned about a decision he has to make, (or in the version narrated by Ibn Mas'ood as: 'if any one of you wants to do something...) then let him pray two rak'ahs of non-obligatory prayer and say (after the Salah) a supplication. 
>
> A translation of the supplication is as follows: 
>
> "O Allah, I seek Your counsel by Your knowledge and I seek Your assistance by Your power and I ask You from Your immense favour, for verily You are able while I am not, and verily You know while I do not, and You are the knower of the Unseen. O Allah, if You know this affair ( mention affair here ) to be good for me in relation to my religion, my life and aftermath, my present and future, then decree it and facilitate it for me, and bless me with it, and if You know this affair to be ill for me concerning my religion, my life and end, my present and future, then remove it from me and remove me from it, and decree for me what is good, whatever it may be, and make me satisfied with it."

**As for the verses, below are some references - You can find more just by searching the word friend / ally / allies in any English translation eBook format of the Qur'an. But you need to read the verses in their full context.** :

> **The Glorious Qur'an - Chapter 5 - Surah Al Maidah - Verses 55 - 57** 
> Your ally is none but Allah and [therefore] His Messenger and
> those who have believed – those who establish prayer and
> give zakah, and they bow [in worship].
> And whoever is an ally of Allah and His Messenger and those
> who have believed – indeed, the party of Allah – they will be
> the predominant.
> O you who have believed, take not those who have taken your
> religion in ridicule and amusement among the ones who were
> given the Scripture before you nor the disbelievers as allies.
> And fear Allah, if you should [truly] be believers.

> **The Glorious Qur'an - Chapter 25 - Surah Al Furqan- Verses 27-29**
> And the Day the wrongdoer will bite on his hands [in regret]
> he will say, "Oh, I wish I had taken with the Messenger a way.
>
> Oh, woe to me! I wish I had not taken that one (the person who misguided him) as a friend.
>
>  He led me away from the remembrance after it had come to
> me. And ever is Satan, to man, a deserter."